# Why printing Integer array Object gives hash code while char array object gives value in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the snippet of the code

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char[] a={'a','b','c',97,'a'};
        System.out.println(a);
        int[] a1={8,6,7};
        System.out.println(a1);
        Integer[] b={10,20,30};
        System.out.println(b);
        }
}
```

Here is the output

```
abcaa
[I@239d5fe6
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@5527f4f9
```

I know it has to deal with `toString()` method. It has been Overridden in char to return the value. hence we are getting the first output as expected
here is the overridden `toString()` method of `java.lang.Character` ..

```
public String toString() {
      char buf[] = {value};//The value of the Character.
      return String.valueOf(buf);
   }
```

But looking at Integer there is also the overridden `toString()` method

```
public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value); //The value of the Integer.
     }
```

Then why printing a1 and b code calls the default `toString()` implementation of the Object class, that is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Also since valueOf makes another Object but then it's common in both the overridden methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is a dedicated method for printing char arrays:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])

> `public void println(char[] x)`
>
> Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line. This method
>   behaves as though it invokes `print(char[])` and then `println()`.
>
> **Parameters**:
>   `x` - an array of chars to print.

Implementation:

> ```
> public void println(char x[]) {
>     synchronized (this) {
>       print(x);
>       newLine();
>    }
> }
> ```

It has nothing to do with the `toString` implementation of the `char[]` class.

Comment: Try to actually add the text section you're talking about, instead of just letting the link.

Comment: So for `int[] a={10};` while printing a it get passed into Object parameter of `println(Object o)` method and hence default Object `toString()` method is called hence giving me hashCode as output . While if i write `Integer a=new Integer(10);` and print a , it get passed into   Object parameter of `println(Object o)`  but since Integer has `toString()` method overridden it gives me 10 as output instead of hash code. Right ? Point me if i've misunderstood this and where

Answer (score 1):

It's beacause in `java.io.PrintSream` class you've an implemtation for `char[]`

```
/**
 * Prints an array of characters and then terminate the line.  This method
 * behaves as though it invokes <code>{@link #print(char[])}</code> and
 * then <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  an array of chars to print.
 */
public void println(char x[]) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Which at the end call an inner method

```
private void write(char buf[]) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                ensureOpen();
                textOut.write(buf);
                textOut.flushBuffer();
                charOut.flushBuffer();
                if (autoFlush) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                        if (buf[i] == '\n')
                            out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }
    }
```

Which loop trough all elements for `char[]`

When you call println whith `int[]` or `Integer[]`, as there is no method having those array in signature, it tooks the one having `Object`

```
 public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you add two answers. You already answered and you're able to edit this answer.

Comment: @Loki To keep trace of my wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you call :

```
 int[] a1={8,6,7};
 System.out.println(a1);
```

You're calling `Integer[].toSTring()` and not `Integer.toSTring()`

You need to either loop on each on your element, or override  `Integer[].toSTring()` to call `toString()` on each of its element.

See for yourself if you write :

```
 System.out.println(a1[0]);
 System.out.println(a1[1]);
 System.out.println(a1[2]);
```

It'll print you the expected output.

Comment: Is there anything called  `Integer[].toSTring()` ? I haven't seen that anywhere ~

Comment: It's not defined, that's why you're getting the default behaviour @AnkurAnand

Comment: i understood that . Have pointed that out in my comment on accepted answer too . point me if i'm wrong at any place there !

Comment: @AnkurAnand No i think you got it. Congratz !

Answer (score 0):

[printStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) has a specific method for printing char[] but does not have method for printing int[] or some other arrays, so when dealing with arrays that are not fo type char[] you are calling the method with Object as parameter whic delegates to `toString()` method which does not iterate on the single elements.

If you want always print the content of the array there is a standard api

> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

Comment: This answer misses an explanation why the `char[]` got printed correctly.

Comment: @Tom you are right I edited my response

Comment: Maybe the downvoters will revert their vote now.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are converting those object to string. You should use toString() method of java.util.Arrays
like:
"Arrays.toString(a1);
Arrays.toString(b)".

Answer (score -2):

Because you're not calling int's toString, or Integer's toString, you're calling Integer[] toString. This creates a textual representation of the objects stored in the Array, not a textual representation of the **value** of the individual objects that are stored.

Comment: This answer misses an explanation why the `char[]` got printed correctly.

Comment: Because that answer was already given above. Adding another would be redundant.

Comment: Well, the downvoters thought differently. Maybe they will revert their vote after your comment.